# motor to move rope sinusoidally

Tags: motors

I'd like to prototype a kind of device to move a rope like a sinusoidal, or similar waveform, it doesn't have to be precise about the waveform, the goal is hide this mechanism in order to show a floating waveform in space for an exhibition. I think to use an electric motor to vibrate one side of the robe and to fix the other side, but I'm not an expert in this field. How to convert the rotatory movement to vibrate the rope? Any hints on how to do this? Thank you

Comment: You will need to get something like a piston.  The crank shaft is your rotary motion that will be supplied by you motor and the piston will travel straight up and down (or left and right if you prefer) in a linear motion.   As for fixing the other side, you can tie it to an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to convert constant-speed rotary motion into a sinusoidal transverse motion, the simplest option is probably a [Scotch Yoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_yoke).

The scotch yoke is mechanically quite simple, so it shouldn't be too hard to build for your application. You can make the piston long so that the scotch yoke and motor are hidden in a box or something. Tie one end of the rope to the piston, fix the other end to a post and you have your waveform. See my simple sketch for an idea of how it works.

[image: A simple sketch of a scotch yoke]

A limitation of this choice is that your oscillation amplitude is determined by the length of the arm/slot, therefore you can't change your amplitude once you have built your device. However if all you want is to move your rope in a general sinusoid pattern it should be ok if the amplitude is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Following on what Forward Ed said, a crank and connecting rod seems like a pretty straight-forward design. I think the motion of the rope will approach a sine wave as the connecting rod is made longer.

I think the free end of the rope might need some attention, too. If you want a travelling sine wave, I think it'll have to have a specific mass added to it (the free end) so that the end doesn't whip around (too little mass), or hang there near motionless (too much mass). Kind of like the kinetic equivalent of a terminating resistor.

If you want a standing sine wave, I think the free end could be held stationary (or maybe nearly-anchored, with just a little bit of stretch), but the relationship between the motor speed and length of rope becomes important. Only certain lengths of rope would produce a standing wave for a given motor speed.